# How to get Unity InputSystem to use OpenXInput or at least DirectInput for XInput controllers?

Tags: unity, input, directinput

I want to workaround the XInput disadvantage of having just four controllers.

I have found out about OpenXInput and compiled it, but I’ve got no idea how to force Unity to use the new DLL, since I did not find any DLL references in InputSystem code.

If it’s not possible, is it at least possible to force those controllers to go through DirectInput, as if they’re non-XInput-compatible? How can that be done?

Comment: This reads like an [XY-Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You are asking about how to get Unity to use alternative gamepad DLL when the actual question you should be asking is "How do I get around the 4 XInput controller limitation?"

Comment: I did ask that before, and Googled a lot. There isn’t a way. The only answer to that is to use DirectInput or OpenXInput. That’s the only way, thus this question. But I don’t know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

While not an expert in the unity Input System package, I have extended a few classes there to perform touch operations on mobile.

I'm pretty sure you would need to create your own adapter classes to expose your native dll, or c# functions through defining a new device type in the input system and managing all the input yourself.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Devices.html#device-descriptions